# Swift Combine - Observe change of object's property publisher inside an array of objects

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

I have a following structure:

```swift
class FileUploadCellViewModel {
    @Published var isUploaded: Bool = false
}

class FileUploadScreenViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewModels: [FileUploadCellViewModel] = []
    @Published var isSendButtonEnabled: Bool = false
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        let publisher = $viewModels
            // ?? return a single publisher with `true` if all `isUploaded` are `true`
        }
        let isDateCorrectPublisher = ...

        publisher
            .combineLatest(isDateCorrectPublisher)
            .sink {
                isSendButtonEnabled = $0 && $1
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

let screen = FileUploadScreenViewModel()
let viewModel1 = FileUploadCellViewModel()
let viewModel2 = FileUploadCellViewModel()

screen.viewModels.append(viewModel1) // expected: isSendButtonEnabled: false
screen.viewModels.append(viewModel2) // expected: isSendButtonEnabled: false

viewModel1.isUploaded = false // expected: isSendButtonEnabled: false
viewModel2.isUploaded = true // expected: isSendButtonEnabled: false
viewModel1.isUploaded = true // expected: isSendButtonEnabled: true
```

How do I observe each insertion into the `viewModels` array **and** after an element is inserted, observe its `isUploaded` property?

I have found a [convenience tool](https://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2019/08/04/combine-latest-collection/) to collect an array of publishers, maybe it would be helpful here.

Comment: i think `FileUploadScreenViewModel ` must confirm to `ObservableObject` to publish changes

Comment: Yes, I forgot to copy this when I prepared this snippet. It is an `ObservableObject` in the original implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with needing a `CombineLatestCollection` for combining all `isUploaded` values of all cell view models.

My answer uses the `combineLatest` operator from the [article](https://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2019/08/04/combine-latest-collection/) you've linked.

Once you've combined all publishers, you simply need to call `allSatisfy` on the `[Bool]` to see if all cell view models finished uploading.

Now the only part missing is updating the subscription whenever the `viewModels` array changes - you can do this by observing the `$viewModel` publisher and passing in the updated array to a method, which combines the `isUploaded` properties of the updated view models.

```
class FileUploadScreenViewModel {
  @Published var viewModels: [FileUploadCellViewModel] = []
  @Published var isSendButtonEnabled: Bool = false

  private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    // Whenever the viewModels array changes, set up the subscription on each element of the array
    $viewModels.sink { [weak self] viewModels in
      self?.bindIsSendButtonEnabled(viewModels: viewModels)
    }.store(in: &subscriptions)
  }

  // Combine all isUploaded values from each element of viewModels and update isSendButtonEnabled accordingly
  private func bindIsSendButtonEnabled(viewModels: [FileUploadCellViewModel]) {
    let areUploaded = viewModels
      .map(\.$isUploaded)
      .combineLatest
      .map { areUploaded in
        areUploaded.allSatisfy { isUploaded in
          isUploaded == true
        }
      }

    let isDateCorrectPublisher = Just(true)

    areUploaded
      .combineLatest(isDateCorrectPublisher)
      .map { $0 && $1 }
      .assign(to: &$isSendButtonEnabled)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just needed that final mix and match of these methods :D

Comment: Every time the array has a new element added or removed from it the previous reference is still attached to it